# How is it possible that a binding shadows the existing binding in `case of` block?

Tags: haskell, scope, let, shadowing, letrec

I have to extract user name and email from `Either` of `AuthResponse`.

I use `case of` construct for it:

```
  let (uname, uemail) =
        case getUserResponseJSON creds of
          Right (GoogleUserResponse uname uemail) -> (uname, uemail)
          _ -> ("", "")
```

But I have this warning for both `uname` and `uemail`:

```
    This binding for ‘uname’ shadows the existing binding
      bound at src/Foundation.hs:240:12
    |
242 |               Right (GoogleUserResponse uname uemail) -> (uname, uemail)
    |
```

I expect that `let (uname, uemail)` is out of the scope of `case of` block.

How is it possible to have this warning from the `case` block if `uname` and `uemail` are not yet defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is possible to have this warning from the case block if uname and uemail still not defined?

These are defined, in the scope outside the `case`, two variables named `uname` and `uemail` are defined. The Haskell compiler can "*tie a knot*". Take for example the following expression where we define an endless list of ones:

```
ones :: [Int]
ones = x
    where x = 1 : x
```

Here we thus define a list that looks like:

```
+-------+
|  (:)  |<,
+---+---+ |
| o | o---'
+-|-+---+
  v
  1
```

So you can define a variable in terms of itself, like you do here. You do not *assign* a value to variable, you *declare* a variable. Furthermore note that the order in which you define variables is *not* per se the order in which you will perform operations. So it is possible that the `(uname, uemail)` is never evaluated, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Haskell's `let` is actually `letrec`.

In `let x = x in ...`, the `x` on the right  refers to the `x` on the left.

The scope of `x`, `y` and `z` in

```
    let 
       x = ...
       y = ...
       z = ...
    in ...
```

are all the code areas indicated with `...`.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the reasons, you are reimplenting `Data.Either.fromRight`.

```
import Data.Either (fromRight)

...

    let defaultResponse = GoogleUserResponse "" ""
        toTuple (GoogleUserResponse x y) = (x,y)  -- parameter names aren't important
        gResponse = fromRight defaultResponse $ getUserResponseJSON creds
        (uname, email) = toTuple gResponse

...
```